# NFC reading problem on Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, nfc

I'm trying to make an app that needs to read NFC tags. However, when I hold a tag to my Nexus S, two other apps (Tags and TagWriter) are listed in the "Select an action" menu, while my app isn't listed. I've searched the internet, and I mostly found things about the manifest. I created the manifest when I was following the [developer's guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html).

I think the application itself works, but I can't really test it if the app doesn't recognize the tags. Any help will be very appreciated!

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="nfc" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
   <!-- Permissions -->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <!-- SDK version -->
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

   <!-- Features -->
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

   <!-- Application settings -->
   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <!-- Simulator activity -->
      <activity android:name=".activity.NfcActivity"" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <!-- User activity -->
      <activity android:name=".activity.TagActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         </intent-filter>
      </activity>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is interesting, I have compared this with my own manifest (my application appears in the activity selection dialog) and it looks pretty similar, at least I cannot find any difference - might be you will... I remember I had the same problem, but I was missing one piece in manifest, but the XML below is working for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.mautilus.nfctep"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

        <!--  Nfc tabs-->
        <activity android:name=".NfcTabActivity"
                  android:label="Nfc Tep">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--  Details activity (NFC information) -->
        <activity android:name=".DetailActivity"
                  android:label="Nfc Tep">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
.... continues...
```

BR
STeN,
petr.mazanec[at]mautilus.com

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I've compared them too and I don't find any difference either. I copied your manifest file (and changed the package/activity names of course), but it didn't work either...

Maybe I need to search for the solution elsewhere, but I don't have any idea where. Is there anything, besides the manifest, I need to configure?

Comment: Hi, another think - I have tried this with the very first version of the API, but with OS 2.3.3 there is more advanced Intent dispatching. Check it here http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.3.html, there is NFC Demo application as well. Kind Regards

Comment: Yes, I based my application on that demo. The demo application doesn't really scan tags, it just simulates the scanning. My app works for those simulated tags, but for real tags it isn't listed in the "Select an option" dialog.